# List of Police Cars in Need for Speed:World

Tags: need-for-speed-world

Does anybody have a list of the police car models used in Need For Speed:World?

Is there any way to drive the police cars?

Comment: "Is there any way to drive the police cars?" -- Not currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list:

- Aston V12 Vantage
- Audi R8 4.2 FSI Quattro
- BMW M3 GTS
- Dodge Challenger Concept
- Dodge Viper SRT-10 ACR (*)
- Ford Mustang Boss 302 '2012
- Ford Crown Victoria
- Ford Crown Victoria (Drag Unit)
- Ford Police Interceptor (*)
- Lamborghini Countach 5000 QuattroValvole
- Lamborghini Gallardo LP550-2 Valentino Balboni
- Lamborghini Murcielago LP640
- Lamborghini Sesto Elemento
- Lotus Evora
- Mazda RX8 '2009
- Mercedes Benz McLaren SLR 722 Edition
- Nissan Silvia S15 (Touge Cop Edition)
- Nissan Skyline 2000GT-R (C10)
- Porsche 911 GT3 RS
- Renault Sport Megane R.S
- Toyota Supra

All cop cars have police lights that you can turn on by pressing 'L' key. These cars are usually not available for purchase unless if there is a cop car sale. You can however win these cars through NFSW events such as Forum Friday (NFSW forums), Tweet it up (Twitter), Guess the car (Facebook). You can also win most of these cars through Car Prize packs, which are packs where you purchase to get a random car.

(*)'d cars are a bit special in that in addition to the lights, they are the only cop cars to also have sirens (Press 'K'). They have traditionally never been part of the cop car sales. The Doge Viper SRT-10 ACR is obtainable through an elite car web deal package and occasional special sales, while the Ford Police Interceptor is ONLY obtainable in Car Prize Packs.

Source: NFSWorld Wikia and experience playing the game.

Answer (score -2):

There is the nissan GT and the Ford GT also there is the lamborghini 1 and 2.